# Apache Commons Fileupload Vulnerabilities, remote code exec, exploit code

Tags: java, security, serialization, file-upload

I want to know exploite code of following vulnerabilities.

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FILEUPLOAD-279

It seems like this vulnerabilities be caused by deserialization vulnerabilities.

- https://www.tenable.com/security/research/tra-2016-12

I interested in whether this vulnerabilities is only object deserialization.

According to [Integrating with ysoserial](https://www.tenable.com/security/research/tra-2016-12), it seems possible to attack by uploading file of serialized object payload.

Is this `uploading file` general file upload?
For example, below code.

```
    // Upload file of serialized object payload in Web Browser by `input type="file"`

    // Server Code
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    factory.setSizeThreshold(0);
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List items = upload.parseRequest(request); // **Here executing attack code??
    ...
```

Or is this `uploading file` receiving serialized object payload(and desirialize ) like Java RMI?

I think only when receiving serialized object payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vulnerability in that situation appears to be the application deserialising untrusted data within a trusted access control context (acc). See Oracle's Secure Coding Guidelines for Java SE [Guideline 8-5 / SERIAL-5: Understand the security permissions given to serialization and deserialization](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#8-5).

A quick look at the [current source](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-fileupload.git;a=blob;f=src/main/java/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItem.java;h=e5e3bf9b02f55e839ad7144aecd040c42f13ac41;hb=HEAD) appears to indicate that the `Serializable` has been taken off that library, and it doesn't appear to have ever done any deserialisation itself (I could be wrong).